# Cloud Foundry UAA test signing key and verification key

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

I'm trying to use cloud foundry's UAA on my local development environment. I  just wanted to set a custom verification and signing key for my custom UAA using a custom UAA.yml file and right now everything is fine. But my question is that where can I check that the previously given settings are working?

```
jwt:
  token:
    verification-key: |
       ------BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
       ...
       -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
    signing-key: |
       -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY---
       ...
```

If I use uaac signing key command the result is the following:

> alg: HMACSHA256
>   value: tokenkey
>    kty: MAC
>    use: sig

Can anyone help to understand it? :)

Answer (score 0):

If the /token_key endpoint is returning what you say it is, then it is not using your RSA key. It's falling back to the built-in default HMAC key. Are you using identity zones, and if so are you targeting a non-default identity zone with UAAC?

Comment: Well I'm not quite familiar with the concept of identity zones. I've read the documentation about it but it isn't so clear to me how to use it and what for. Could you help to get a better understanding about this idenetity zones? By the way I use the default settings.